# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't see bootable pendrive

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, usb-drive

I am a newbie when it comes to install Ubuntu so I apologize in advance if my question has been already answered. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a Macbook Pro from 2012 with Nvidia GeForce graphical card 320M. It was running fine but I had problem with the screen brightness so I tried to go to Software & Updates, Additional Drivers and I chose to use the original driver for the Nvidia card and Broadcom wifi. I rebooted and Ubuntu didn't boot at all. I then switched the pc on, went to the grub, pressed 'e' and added nomodeset. It didn't work, so I switched the pc off and on again, accessed the grub and added nouveau.modeset=0. It didn't work either. I tried to put the same usb with Ubuntu liveUsb that I used to previously to install Ubuntu on the Mac and I can't see the nor load Ubuntu from the pendrive. If I access the grub, I can only see

- Ubuntu
- Options

I can't see any other option to start Ubuntu from the pendrive. I would love to reinstall Ubuntu because right now I have a pc that doesn't work. After hours of frustrating attempts, I don't know what else to do. Any help? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: To boot from an external USB device you need to use your computer's built-in firmware boot selection menu; when poor Grub has been loaded and running it's too late to select the USB device.

Comment: Hi @AlexP, thanks for replying. Unfortunately I don't understand the implications of what you told me. Does it mean that there is nothing I can do? Do I have to buy another hard disk? Thanks

Comment: No, no. What I wanted to say was that if you want to boot from the installation USB flash drive you must use your computer's firmware boot selection menu; you cannot wait until GRUB has loaded, because by that time it's too late to select the USB flash drive as boot device. Boot the installation USB flash drive in the same way you did when you installed Ubuntu and go to a live session (= "Try Ubuntu").

Comment: ok, I did that. I press esc when I hear the chime of the Mac. I see a screen with only two options

- Ubuntu
- Advanced Options

At this stage I don't see any pendrive. That's my proble, so I can't try the Ubuntu I have on the pendrive...Any help at this stage?

Comment: Update: I pressed the "option" key on the mac keyboard at the startup and it only showed one hard disk and no pendrive so I can't "try Ubuntu". I got what you were talking about and I was so exhausted that I didn't see what was right in front of my eyes. Unfortunately, I still can't see the pendrive.

Any comment on that? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I just tried to see whether the pendrive works by restarting my other Mac, a Macbook Air. I press the option key and I can definitely see the pendrive. I don't know what went wrong with the Macbook Pro. Before installing Ubuntu, I could see the pendrive and that's how I managed to go further with the installation.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help any further. I have very little knowledge of Apple devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I'm now installing Ubuntu on a another usb and check whether I will be able to see the it from the macbook pro. I hope to be able to fix this problem but my hope is decreasing a lot...I truly feel lost :(

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] the solution was fairly simple. The Macbook Pro didn't see the pendrive if it's already plugged in when rebooting. I solved my problem by chance by plugging it out and in again. Then the mac could see it. So what I needed to do was

1. plug the usb out
2. reboot
3. press the option key when I heard the chime
4. Mac was showing the number of hard disks
5. I plugged the usb in
6. I was able to boot from the usb